# Remember SmartCard PIN using Java Applet for accessing Keystore

Tags: java, applet, keystore, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am able to access to a SmartCard with a Java Applet (embedded) using MS CryptoAPI and PKCS#11 (registering the provider with the .dll). I can use both, but right now I'm using the CryptoAPI one for having an easier support for all keyboards/Windows versions:

```
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keystore.load(null,null);
```

I'm using Javascript to comunicate with Java to sign some operations in a web application I am developing.

The default use case is just what I need:

- I get/load the Keystore
- I try to sign something, it ask for the PIN and once introduced it remembers until the end of the session (when I extract the SmartCard or cache timeout).

The problem is: It's an embedded Applet. When I sign something in web page A and then I go to web page B (through a link or redirect, for ex.), the Applet is destroyed/created (just like the JVM) and the session is lost so I have to introduce again the PIN. This does not happen if I do not leave/reload the actual web page, of course.

Questions: Is there some way to reuse the session/Applet/JVM programmatically? or loading the Keystore in a way that can avoid this problem?

Possible workaround solutions I already know:

- Free floating Applet. I can't, it has no GUI and I need to comunicate with JS...
- Web in a frameset/iframe. Dirty.
- Ajaxify the web (just one page + all operations in Ajax + some kind of history JS plugin or PushState). This is the solution I like more but requires some refactoring.

Comment: Personally I *like* it when a smart card requires re-entering my PIN. If it doesn't, how do I know that my PIN isn't lost, or if my smart card is not signing stuff on my behalf?

Comment: I agree with owlstead: caching PINs should be avoided if possible; especially in signature context the entry of the PIN is considered to be the willful act to agree with the action performed. I would trust no software to do it for me. For me the solution seems to  have an additional key not protected by a PIN but by a challenge-response test. We are talking about just a few smart card APDUs here, this is not really difficult.

Comment: There's always a compromise between security and usability, specially if you do a lot of ops during the day. And it's true there's a risk if you leave the computer with the smartcard inside the PIN cached and the screen not locked. I could agree or not, but the thing is it's a requirement :-)

Comment: @jBilbo: many customers/bosses/stake holders may even drop requirements after a reasonable explanation, weakening the purpose of the PIN (catch-word non-repudiation) is one of these in my opinion. I also guess the requirement is not "please cache the PIN" but more like "I want a card holder authentication just once per session/day but for arbitrary many foobars". Correct? So you have to use an externally provided smart card, which can't be adapted to match this scenario?

Comment: @guidot I'm replacing part of a software and trying to replicate this (legacy) behavior, mainly because users are used to work this way. But anyway, that's unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it in a completely different way: Creating a client desktop app for the signature. This app is installed in all desktop clients (this is ok for me because it's a corporate environment).
This new app listens to a port with a `HttpListener`. I connect from the web via javascript (jsonp), send the string to be signed, and it returns the js callback with the result signed.

- It now remembers the PIN because it does not lose the session.
- And, therefore, do not need Java.